# List of dictionaries to summarise

Tags: python, python-3.x, iteration, python-itertools

There is a list of dictionaries:

```
given_list = [
    {"cat_id": 1, "category": "red", "items": 1},
    {"cat_id": 1, "category": "red", "items": 3},
    {"cat_id": 2, "category": "yellow", "items": 2},
    {"cat_id": 2, "category": "yellow", "items": 4},
    {"cat_id": 2, "category": "yellow", "items": 6},
    {"cat_id": 3, "category": "green", "items": 99},
]
```

The outcome should be another list, where items are summarized:

```
outcome = [
    {"cat_id": 1, "category": "red", "items": 4},
    {"cat_id": 2, "category": "yellow", "items": 12},
    {"cat_id": 3, "category": "green", "items": 99}
]
```

Please advise the best way to make this.

Details of the question:

- "cat_id" always match "category"
- "cat_id" not necessary ordered in the given list
- the mix of different dict items in a random way is possible
- the outcome should be only this structure: list of dicts

Comment: What happens to `{"cat_id": 1, "category": "yellow", "items": 1}`?

Comment: Is the list always ordered?

Comment: Would you consider making the outcome a dictionary? e.g. `outcome={1: {'category': 'red', 'items': 4}, 2: ..., 3: ...}`

Comment: clarification was added into the details of the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) in itertools module. So basically you group the dictionaries based on the value of the `"cat_id"`. In the for loop, you get the first dictionary and add it to the final result list, then for the rest of the dictionaries exist in the group, you just increment the value of `"items"`.

```py
from itertools import groupby

given_list = [
    {"cat_id": 1, "category": "red", "items": 1},
    {"cat_id": 1, "category": "red", "items": 3},
    {"cat_id": 2, "category": "yellow", "items": 2},
    {"cat_id": 2, "category": "yellow", "items": 4},
    {"cat_id": 2, "category": "yellow", "items": 6},
    {"cat_id": 3, "category": "green", "items": 99},
]

outcome = []
for _, g in groupby(given_list, key=lambda x: x["cat_id"]):
    outcome.append(next(g))
    for d in g:
        outcome[-1]["items"] += d["items"]
```

One thing to note is that your data should already be sorted with this approach. If not you need to first sort it. This is how `groupby` works.

Comment: This will fail if `cat_id` does not match `category` 1:1, or if the list is not ordered by `cat_id`

Comment: @MadPhysicist I already noted about the ordering in my answer, but for that assumption you're right the question is not detailed enough.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data=given_list)
new_dict = (
   df.groupby(["cat_id","category"])
     .sum().reset_index()
).to_dict(orient="records")
```

the output for `new_dict` will be

```
[{'cat_id': 1, 'category': 'red', 'items': 4},
 {'cat_id': 2, 'category': 'yellow', 'items': 12},
 {'cat_id': 3, 'category': 'green', 'items': 99}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Python is providing you the easy and straight forward answer with the **defaultdict**

```
given_list = [
{"cat_id": 1, "category": "red", "items": 1},
{"cat_id": 1, "category": "red", "items": 3},
{"cat_id": 2, "category": "yellow", "items": 2},
{"cat_id": 2, "category": "yellow", "items": 4},
{"cat_id": 2, "category": "yellow", "items": 6},
{"cat_id": 3, "category": "green", "items": 99},]

def nested_dict(n, type):
if n == 1:
    return defaultdict(type)
else:
    return defaultdict(lambda: nested_dict(n-1, type))

from collections import defaultdict
output_list = []
tmp = nested_dict(2, int)

for i in given_list:
    for key, value in i.items():
        if key == "cat_id":
            tmp_key_1 = str(value)
        elif key == "category":
            tmp_key_2 = str(value)
        else:
            tmp[tmp_key_1][tmp_key_2] += value

for key, value in tmp.items():
    for key_1, value_1 in value.items():
        output_list.append({"cat_id":key, "category":key_1, "items":value_1})
```

Finally, your **output_list** will have the expected result.